# How Get Url on Startup asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

How get the url (EX:localhost:52144) on Startup method in asp.net mvc4?

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       //Get here the URL
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code below to get the complete url

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       //Get here the URL
       HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Works, but with not good answer (AbsoluteUri "http://127.0.0.1/"), but in a controller works fine (localhost:XXXX)